# Container should have the same height

Tags: flutter

I want that the red container has the same height as the blue container. The problem is, that the height of the blue container changes depending of the amount of lines. It would also help if the red container starts on the same height as blue container. The goal is to have a functional bullet point in the middle of the first line

My code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InhaltGesetz extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const InhaltGesetz({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: 70,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: const Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0, -0.99),
              child: Text(
                '•',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Container(
              width: 340,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 8, 8, 8),
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.5,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I do not know what to do I tried to change the height manually with every container but i ended up with 9000+ lines of code and i will not do it any longer

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you much but you can use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` in your `Row` to align the top of both containers. You can also use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to make both of them the same height (which will work), but then they will take up all the space and you would need to constrain the height again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntrinsicHeight` widget(expensive), Follow this structure.

```dart
class InhaltGesetz extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, -0.99),
                  child: Text(
                    '•',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 340,
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```